# Derivation of HJB equation and Ito lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, poisson-process, stochastic-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

As per [Avellaneda and Stoikov market-making model](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Eavellane/HighFrequencyTrading.pdf), the HJB equation is defined as
[image]

where function $u$ is the value function.

The question is how do derive the 1st HJB equation, which is just the time differential of $du(s,x,q,t)$?

My attempt is to apply Ito lemma on the wealth process directly
$$q_{t}S_{t}+X_{t}$$
where $W_t$ is Brownian motion, $N_t^a$ and $N_t^b$ are independent Poisson random variables with intensities $\lambda^a(\delta^a)$ and $\lambda^b(\delta^b)$, which are some decreasing functions of $\delta^a$ and $\delta^b$.
$$dS_t=\sigma dW_t$$
$$dq_t=dN_t^b-dN_t^a$$
$$dX_t=p^a dN_t^a-p^b dN_t^b$$
However, applying Ito lemma results in coefficient on $u_{ss}$ becoming $\sigma^{2}\left(N_{t}^{b}-N_{t}^{a}\right)^{2}$, instead of just $\sigma^{2}$. Is this a correct approach? Or perhaps we should apply multidimensional Ito lemma on the system of three processes $dS_t,dX_t,dq_t$, ie
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
dS_{t}\\
dX_{t}\\
dq_{t}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\sigma\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right]dW_{t}+\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
p^{a} & -p^{b}\\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
dN_{t}^{a}\\
dN_{t}^{b}
\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: Avellaneda & Stoikov write *clearly* that this HJB equation was shown in a paper by Ho and Stoll (1981). You should probably make the efford to read that then.

Comment: You should probably not comment if you cannot be bothered to add anything useful.

Comment: Probably. Why is it you don't want to follow the paths the authors had gone ? Presumably it is not that simple.

Comment: Not as simple as assuming I haven't read it, it is as you said clearly stated and I have read it. It is still not clear to me, hence my question.

Comment: Sounds better. Note that $u(s,x,q,t)$ is a deterministic function of the deterministic variables $s,x,q,t\,.$ That HJB equation is analogous to the heat equation which is the PDE $\partial_t u+\Delta u=0$ that is satisifed by $u(t,x)=E[f(W_T)|W_t=x]\,.$ This can be learned nicely in Karatzas Shreve's book. Surely the Ito lemma plays an important role here. I could not get acces to Ho & Stoll (1981) but recommend to study the more standard BM / heat equation stuff first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I will check that.

Comment: Ho and Stoll actually use Ito lemma for that, but then again their results are not quite the same as what Avellaneda and Stoikov wrote. My dissertation supervisor hinted on using Ito lemma, then the principle of optimality and martingale properties of Poisson random variables (after compensating) with the Brownian motion to deduce the $[...]dt = 0$